# How to Artisan (specifically migrate command) on non-laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm just wondering if anyone have been able to do this?

I have been able to use Eloquent by adding `illuminate/database` to composer.json

I believe the necessary files are already included in `illuminate/database` but having trouble figuring out on how to call it through terminal because I don't have the artisan command line.

So just wandering if I can actually have the Artisan CLI to allow me to do the migration.

Answer (score 0):

All Artisan commands registered through `Illuminate\Foundation\Application::register()` method,
and  `Illuminate\Foundation` require all illuminate component, means that if we have to use `Artisan`, we need a laravel apps.

I think, it just fine to use artisan to only manage database for non-laravel project. You can, but yes you also have to install laravel, just install in separate location and  create proper database config fit to your project.

> I believe the necessary files are already included in
>   `illuminate/database`

`Illuminate\Database\Console` ? it's nothing without Artisan.

I suggest to just install laravel, and use it's artisan to only manage your project database. If you dont want laravel, you can use other migration tools e.g [doctrine-migration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html) since db-migration is separated, have no relation with your codes.